# python: loadtext function problem: "could not convert string to float"

Tags: python, dataframe, file, opencsv

I am trying to open a .dat file by using loadtxt function in python but I got stuck and I know it is because of the form of the input file. It consists of columns of numbers but at certain columns there are no values and you just find several commas "," in a row. Commas are the delimiters. The input would be like this:

```
,2,,,1,3,3,4
,1,,,4,5,7,7
,1,,,2,4,6,8
```

The code is as follows:

````
import numpy as np

MR= np.loadtxt('....R_xx_vs_perp_field_5K.dat', skiprows=32, delimiter=',')
print(MR[4,3])```
````

When running the code I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:....pruebas_loadtxt.py", line 3, in <module>
    MR= np.loadtxt('....R_xx_vs_perp_field_5K.dat', skiprows=32, delimiter=',')
  File "C:...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1139, in loadtxt
    for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
  File "C:...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1067, in read_data
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1067, in <listcomp>
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "C:....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 763, in floatconv
    return float(x)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

I know the error is related to the fact that I have several commas
in a row because once you remove them you get no error.
I would like not to remove then in order to make the process as automatic as possible. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `np.genfromtxt`:

```
>>> np.genfromtxt('example.txt', delimiter=',')
array([[nan,  2., nan, nan,  1.,  3.,  3.,  4.],
       [nan,  1., nan, nan,  4.,  5.,  7.,  7.],
       [nan,  1., nan, nan,  2.,  4.,  6.,  8.]])
```

Comment: I have already solved the problem. I can just use the parameter usecol from loadtxt function and choose just the right columns so the function will ignore the others. It works perfectly. Thank you anyway